# Use a variable in the main function to define the size of an array via malloc outside main?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

So as a beginner pointers are my newly declared archnemesis but unfortunately I feel like I have to use them for this task.

The user has to define the length of an array in the main function via a simple scanf function (the function exists to check if the interval of the input-value is valid):

`arraylength = input();`

I then initialize the array with another previously declared array pointer, using the array length as a parameter:

`int *array = init_array (arraylength);`

```
int* init_array(int arraylength)
{
    int *array = (int*) malloc ((arraylength) * (sizeof (int));

    return array;
}
```

I am getting error messages and I know that I'm using `malloc` the wrong way.
But I'm confused because I just can't find the mistake. The syntax looks right to me  (then again I am a beginner)

I think it either has something to do with how I am using pointers the wrong way and the data types of`int arraylength`  and  `int *array`. 
Playing around with the data types (changing them from pointer to normal integer and vice versa) just subsequently creates more warnings and errors.

We are not allowed to use any 
`const` variables by the way.
 Every variable must be declared within the functions.

Comment: "I am getting error messages". It should be obvious but you should provide the exact error messages - edit your question and paste those directly in. Also, please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

If this is the same error, you forgot to put a parenthesis at the end of malloc

```
// This
int *array = (int*) malloc ((arraylength) * (sizeof (int)));
// Not this
int *array = (int*) malloc ((arraylength) * (sizeof (int));
```

Also you do not need to typecast **(int*)** in malloc, unless you are using c++, just extra code with no reason to,

```
int *array = malloc ((arraylength) * (sizeof (int)));
```

This is just fine

Comment: or perhaps get rid of the redundant parentheses !

Comment: @M.M yes that too

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this out now!

Comment: @MarinaS. no problem, tell me if it works, if not i can help again!

Comment: Malloc worked(there's no warning anymore related to it)  but now I'm having other problems related to return *array

Comment: @MarinaS.if you created another question with code it might be easier for me to help rather than commenting a lot, also i could see code better

Answer (score -2):

Use the correct types. It is better to `sizeof` objects not types.

```
void *init_array(const size_t arraylength)
{
    int *array = malloc (arraylength * sizeof (*array));
    return array;
}
```